# How to catch FusionTablesLayer errors?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm fairly new to the Google Maps API and unlikely to get things right the first time..
The documentation doesn't seem to provide any way to check errors on things like the `FusionTablesLayer` constructor, for example a query error.

In the interests of saving development time and building a more robust solution, is there a way to catch errors on the `FusionTablesLayer` constructor, or in general for the maps API?

Comment: To help debug errors: check that the table has public or link access; and debug the query from the browser like so: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started#SQL

Comment: Also check that the data you've been given is correct; that it shows in the Fusion Table's map tab.